# Does (If not P then Q) imply (If P then Q)? My truth table says yes but I want verification

Tags: logic

As the title says, is this true?

$$(\lnot P \to \lnot Q) \to (P \to Q)$$

The truth table is

\begin{array}{rrrrrr}
              P & Q & \lnot P & \lnot Q & \lnot P \to \lnot Q & P \to Q & (\lnot P \to \lnot Q) \to (P \to Q)   \\ \hline
           T &   T &   F &   F &   T &   T &  T \\
           T &   F &   F &   T &   T &   F &  F \\
           F &   T &   T &   F &   F &   T &  T \\
           F &   F &   T &   T &   T &   T & T \\ 
\end{array}

It seems like it's true from the table.

If it is true, is it true because $$(\lnot P \to \lnot Q) \to (P \to Q)$$ has the same truth table corresponding to the $\to$ connective which is false only when the antecedent is T but the consequent is F?

Or is it true because the statement is true when the premises of $\lnot P \to \lnot Q$ and $P \to Q$ are true?

If it's not true, why not?

Comment: Why would it seem to you like it is true from the truth table?  You have a F in the last column.  That indicates that it is not a tautology.

Comment: The title suggests the formula you want is $(\neg P\to Q)\to(P\to Q)$ not $(\neg P\to\neg Q)\to(P\to Q)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(\lnot P\to\lnot Q)\to(P\to Q)$ is *not a tautology* because it is not true when $P$ is true but $Q$ is false.   That is shown in the second row of your truth table.

Likewise, it is not a contradiction.   The statement is *conditionally* true.

The statement is logically equivalent to $\lnot(P\land\lnot Q)$, also to $(\lnot P\lor Q)$.

---

Now $(\lnot P\to\lnot Q)\to(Q\to P)$ *is* a tautology in classical logic.   Notice the order of the terms.

Indeed $\lnot P\to \lnot Q$ is the contrapositive of $Q\to P$, and the two are logically equivalent.

Comment: Is it conditionally true because (¬P→¬Q) is a premise and (P→Q) is a conclusion, and the conclusion is false when the premise is true when P is true and Q is false? In other words whether this statement is true or not doesn't have anything to do with the evaluation of (¬P→¬Q)→(P→Q) itself i.e. I can remove the last column and be able to evaluate the truth table

Comment: "In other words whether this statement is true or not doesn't have anything to do with the evaluation of $(\neg P\to \neg Q)\to (P\to Q)$ itself", except that truth is defined exactly by the result of [valuations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valuation_(logic)).

Comment: @GitGud Ok so the last column is necessary because it gives us the final statement to evaluate it's truthfulness correct?

Comment: I have a question. Is (¬P→¬Q) the premise and (P→Q) the conclusion? Or are they both premises with (¬P→¬Q)→(P→Q)  as the conclusion?

Comment: @000 We say $\lnot P\to\lnot Q$ is the *antecedant*, and $P\to Q$ is the *consequent*, of the *statement* $(\lnot P\to\lnot Q)\to(P\to Q)$.  *Premise* and *conclusion* reference parts of a logical argument.

Comment: @GrahamKemp I see premise and conclusion being used to describe logical arguments. What is the appropriate context to use those terms?

Comment: A premise is an undischarged assumption.  The conclusion is the final derivation made.  The argument is intended to convince that the premises logically entail the conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

No, if we have a statement "$P$ then $Q$", then "$\neg P$ then $\neg Q$" is the inverse of the statement. The inverse being true does not imply the statement is true.

For instance consider a class where the cutoff for an $A$ is $90\%$. Consider the statement $$
\text{"If you have above an }80\%\text{, then you will receive an }A\text{."}
$$ 
This statement is not true. However its inverse is true.
$$
\text{"If you do not have above an }80\%\text{, then you will not receive an }A\text{."}
$$

Comment: Thank you. Is (¬P→¬Q) the premise and (P→Q) the conclusion? Or are they both premises with (¬P→¬Q)→(P→Q)  as the conclusion?

Comment: ($\neg P\rightarrow \neg Q$) is the premise or hypothesis and ($P\rightarrow Q$) is the conclusion.